# Understand clearly about PersistenceContext and PersistenceUnit in JPA

Tags: jpa-2.0

I am new JPA, i did not understand clearly about PersistenceContext and PersistenceUnit in JPA. Pls Expalin if you

- Explain about PersistenceContext and PersistenceUnit annotations in JPA.
- Differences between PersistenceContext and PersistenceUnit ?

and  explain where to use and a small scenario(example).

Answer (score 0):

A `persistence unit` defines information and settings for interacting with a database. This includes connection data as well as info regarding table creation. This is usually done with a xml file called `persistence.xml`

A `persistence context` is uses the `persistence.xml` file and provides and API for actually interacting with the database.